# Using require to split gulp tasks into multiple files causes task not found

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gulp

Recently our project has gone over a bit of a rehaul for structure and afterwards we've been having some troubles with our gulpfile.

I've followed the advice from [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/split-tasks-across-multiple-files.md) in order to split out our code into tasks but for some reason I'm still always met with 
`Task 'start' is not in your gulpfile`

This only happens on everyone else's machine but mine, as well making it very difficult to debug.

I've also tried using `require` to require each file individually, but I'm still met with the same error.

**What could be causing this error and where can I start debugging?**

#### Gulpfile

```
'use strict'

var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    $           = require('gulp-load-plugins')(),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    path        = require('path'),
    del         = require('del'),
    merge       = require('merge2')

var context = path.resolve(__dirname, 'agency/tasks')

require(path.resolve(context, 'build.js'))
require(path.resolve(context, 'clean.js'))
require(path.resolve(context, 'compile.js'))
require(path.resolve(context, 'file_path.js'))
require(path.resolve(context, 'inject.js'))
require(path.resolve(context, 'start.js'))
require(path.resolve(context, 'stream_factory.js'))
require(path.resolve(context, 'watch.js'))

// Previously tried 
// require('require-dir')('./agency/tasks') 

gulp.task('default', ['start']);

gulp.task('build:common:clean', function() {
  return del('commonBuild', {force: true})
})

gulp.task('build:common', ['build:common:clean'], function() {
  var buildJade = gulp.src('common/**/*.jade')
    .pipe($.jade({pretty: true}))
    .pipe($.ngHtml2js({
      declareModule: false,
      moduleName: 'edvisor.common'
    }))

  var buildModules =  gulp.src(['common/**/*.js', '!common/index.js'])
    .pipe($.babel({externalHelpers: true}))
    .pipe($.angularFilesort())

  var buildIndex = gulp.src('common/index.js')
    .pipe($.babel({externalHelpers: true}))

  return merge(merge(buildModules, buildIndex), buildJade)
    .pipe($.concat('index.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('commonBuild'))
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my coworkers ended up solving this. The reason was we had a `node_modules` folder within the `agency` folder. This caused gulp to what I assume use the gulp within the `agency/node_modules` so when `require-dir` was complete it wouldn't have the tasks that were in those files.